# The plot_ly() displays in hover info twice color and y attribute instead of just one

Tags: r, plotly

my data :

```
df<-structure(list(`Hospital Region` = structure(1:8, levels = c("LA-Santa Barbara-Ventura", 
"Mid-Coastal", "North Coast-East Bay", "Northeastern", "Orange", 
"San Diego-Imperial", "Southern Central Valley", "Southern Inland"
), class = "factor"), Count = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

the issue is that in hoverinfo the hospital region is displayd twice as both `color` and `y`

```
fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~Count, y = ~`Hospital Region`, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h',color=~`Hospital Region`)
    
fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify `hoverinfo = "text"` and then specify columns in `text` as what you want to show on hover.

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~Count, y = ~`Hospital Region`, type = 'bar', 
               orientation = 'h',color=~`Hospital Region`, 
                hoverinfo = "text", text = ~`Hospital Region`)
fig
```

[image]